# Как работает каскадное добавление елементов в DOM в Javascript?

Tags: javascript, dom, table

Вот очень простой пример создания таблички. Помогите понять, почему первый вариант работает, а второй нет, хотя по факту он должен был бы быть полностью эквивалентным?

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
var td = document.createElement("td");
var text = document.createTextNode("Пример 1");
td.appendChild(text);
tr.appendChild(td);
table.appendChild(tr);
document.body.appendChild(table);

document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement('table').appendChild(
    document.createElement('tr').appendChild(
      document.createElement('td').appendChild(
        document.createTextNode('Пример 2')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Что любопытно, выходит что `appendChild` возвращает добавленный елемент, поэтому вот эти два варианта также работают:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('table'))
             .appendChild(document.createElement('tr'))
             .appendChild(document.createElement('td'))
             .appendChild(document.createTextNode('Пример 3'));

var table1 = document.createElement("table");
var table2 = document.body.appendChild(table1);
var tr1 = document.createElement("tr");
var tr2 = table2.appendChild(tr1);
var td1 = document.createElement("td");
var td2 = tr2.appendChild(td1);
var text = document.createTextNode("Пример 4");
td2.appendChild(text);
```

Пример 3 и 4 по-идее эквивалентны, как и 1 и 2. Работают все кроме 2.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Что любопытно, выходит что appendChild возвращает добавленный елемент

Именно поэтому второй вариант и не работает. Код

```
document.createElement('tr').appendChild(
  document.createElement('td').appendChild(
    document.createTextNode('Пример 2')
  )
)
```

равносилен

```
var text1 = document.createTextNode('Пример 2');
var text2 = document.createElement('td').appendChild(text1)
var text3 = document.createElement('tr').appendChild(text2)
```

Вы добавляете 'Пример 2' и в td, и в tr, и далее, а td в документ не добавляется. Если бы appendChild возвращал элемент, в который происходит добавление, то второй вариант бы работал, но третий работал бы некорректно

Comment: замечательный ответ, спасибо! не понимаю, как я сразу не связала это все, когда стало ясно как работает `appendChild()`

Answer (score 0):

Потому что добавляется возвращаемый елемент, а не тот который был создан. То есть в конструкции

```
document.body.appendChild(
  document.createElement('table').appendChild(
    document.createElement('tr').appendChild(
      document.createElement('td').appendChild(
        document.createTextNode('Пример 2')
      )
    )
  )
);
```

по сути ничего не добавляется, кроме `'Пример 2'`, который возвращается из всех `appendChild()`.

> **Заметки:**
>
> Цепочка может работать не так, как ожидалось из-за того, что
>   `appendChild()` возвращает дочерний элемент:
>
> ```
> var aBlock = doc.createElement ('block'). appendChild (doc.createElement ('b'));
> ```
>
> Устанавливает `aBlock` только `<b> </ b>`, чего вы, скорее всего, не
>   хотите.

Comment: спасибо за ответ! теперь все понятно.